# Proper way to organize diagnostic tests in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, filesystems, diagnostics

I am working on a `Spring-based web-application` that uses several components, including `PostgreSQL`, `raw filesystem` and more..

I want to make a small admin-page, where an admin will be able to test, if all components are working propery, e.g.:

- if `PostgreSQL` is up, running, and accepts reads/writes
- if the `FileSystem` is accesible, if there is some space left etc.
- the same for other modules

Do you know of a design solution for this kind of problems (diagnostics/self-checks) ?
Should I create methods in the modules that use those components (e.g. in PostgreSQL data access layer) that perform dummy writes and reads confiriming, that the given service/component is working?

Answer (score 1):

You should write MBean using [JMX technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html) for every resource you want to monitor. Implementation of MBeans is up to you (yes, you may do read/writes for DBMS for example).

Comment: what is the benefit of using JMX if I have to write the read/write logic anyway?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/why.html The main idea of having separate component for monitoring is not to depend on availability of your webapp. JMX is standard technology in Java for that purpose, and you asked for _design_ solution. If you just need to monitor system resources and such common things, there are ready-to-use solutions like https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/ Application servers by itself contain MBeans to monitor everything inside them. What App Server do you use?

Comment: Tomcat, but its a.distributed app - dbs are on different machines